# Write a recurrence for the probability that the champion retains the title?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

**Problem:**

> The traditional world chess championship is a match of 24 games. The
> current champion retains the title in case the match is a tie. Each
> game ends in a win, loss, or draw (tie) where wins count as 1, losses
> as 0, and draws as 1/2. The players take turns playing white and
> black. White plays first and so has an advantage. The champion plays
> white in the first game. The champ has probabilities ww, wd, and wl of
> winning, drawing, and losing playing white, and has probabilities bw,
> bd, and bl of winning, drawing, and losing playing black.
>
> (a) Write a recurrence for the probability that the champion retains the title.
> Assume that there are g games left to play in the match and that the
> champion needs to get i points (which may be a multiple of 1/2).

I found this problem in skiena's Algorithm design manual book and tried to solve it.

My take on this problem is At i`th game a champion must either win , lose or tie the game.we have prior probability of ww,wd and wl(since champion starts from white I am considering only ww,wd and wl only).
so the probability that the champion will win is equal to  current outcome weightage multiplied by prior probability,

`P_win(i) = ∑(prior_p * current_outcome_weightage) = ((ww*win_weight)+(wd*draw_weight)+(wl*loss_weight))/3`

current outcome weightage is either one of the three case:

1. if champion wins : win_weight=1,draw_weight=0,loss_weight=0
2. if champion loses: win_weight=0,draw_weight=0,loss_weight=0
3. if champion draws: win_weight=0,draw_weight=1/2,loss_weight=0

> Is there any better way to write the recurrence for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to "guess" at the current probability if the champion wins loses or draws, and recurse based on it, modifying `i` according to win/loss/draw - and always reducing `g`.

Stop clause is if either champion wins (no more points needed) or loses (no more games left).

```
(Note, conditions are evaluated in order, so g==0, i==0 will apply g<=0 only, for example)
    Sol(g, i) =  {
    i <= 0:               1
    g == 0:               0
    i%2 == 0:             ww*Sol(g-1, i-1) + wd*Sol(g-1,i-1/2) + wl*Sol(g-1,i)
    i%2 == 1:             bw*Sol(g-1, i-1) + bd*Sol(g-1,i-1/2) + bl*Sol(g-1,i)
}
```

Quick sanity test, if there is a final match left, and the champion must win it - then the probability of him winning is `bw`. In this case you need to evaluate: `Sol(1, 1) = bw*Sol(0,0) + bd*Sol(0,1/2) + bl*Sol(0,1) = bw*1 + bd*0 + bl*0 = bw`

Comment: Could you please explain in your answer what `g` and `i` stand for? Especially since the question used variable `i` to refer to something and you use it to refer to something else.

Comment: @Stef Thanks, I simply reversed their roles (mistake). Editing to match the description in the question: ` Write a recurrence for the probability that the champion retains the title. Assume that there are **g games left** to play in the match and that the champion needs to **get i points** (which may be a multiple of 1/2).`